# Potentiometer schematic symbol help

Tags: potentiometer, symbol

I cant figure out which pin is the number 1 on the potentiometer and variable resistors within this schematic.  I would guess that the circle with a slash through it is pin one but I'm not sure.  Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks in advance!!!  Schematic link below.

http://www.tonehome.de/app/download/10398205/Ibanez_AD100_schematic.pdf

Comment: No. The circle with a slash through it means it is a PC mounted trim pot. You use a tiny flat tip screw driver to adjust it. End points, if marked at all, usually have a CW or CCW marking for 'clockwise' or 'counter-clockwise' end. These are often crucial fine-trim adjustments and to tamper with them is asking for trouble.

Comment: I don't have this unit but I would like one.  Im making a PCB for myself and a friend but cant figure out the pins on the schematic.  I suppose i could just switch the wires as im not board mounting the pots.  Thanks for your help though, I always wondered what the circle with a slash through it meant and now I know.

Answer (score 2):

Trimpots especially multi-turn pots are often numbered with pin 1 being the CCW position and 3 for CW.

**Since it is not marked** (as one would hope) on the schematic, you may hope what see is the minimum position is pin 1 (CCW).

This "standard" was started by Bourns and but it's hard to say if it is still universal.